# Suggestions on how to store temporary rails data for subsequent controller calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, temporary-files

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to store a temporary data object in rails so that it is available after an html view has been rendered?  The data object is fairly large because it is storing a decent amount of data rendered from a batch of remote API calls.  Once the view is rendered, I don't want to have to pull the data a second time in order to generate an export (will take too long because of request throttling), but rather want to just pass the same data object to the appropriate controller method to render a CSV file.

My first though was to pass the variable in the URL, but my suspicions on it being too large were quickly confirmed.  Perhaps temporary data storage somwhere?

Comment: UPDATE: I've already tried storing the data in the session, but as I expected, it would be far too big.

Comment: See caching options.

Comment: Good idea.  Seems to be a functional solution.